# What is the best model to make the use of Amazon AWS scale automatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

That is I have two models either by adding new instance or by upgrading type of instance.
So, which is more preferable and in what circumstances which model should be used?

Comment: How were you planning on "upgrading the type of instance" with autoscaling? By mapping a launch configuration with a different instance type to the autoscaling group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is similar to the [vertical vs. horizontal scalability concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability#Scale_horizontally_vs._vertically).
It is a trade-off, and the best approach normally involves a mix of both, and mostly depends on the nature of your system.

Comment: @noobdj your thanks are appreciated, but you are supposed to accept answers that helped you and, if applicable, upvote them :)

Comment: I can not upvote it because it needs atleast 15 reputation points. :)